# How do I select the nth child of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the display style of three stacked pictures based on the picture I hover on. Apparently it's impossible to go up to the parent and to the next with CSS `:hover`.

I tried to use parts of code I found to get it working. JavaScript works on the first child but I can't get it to display the 2nd child instead.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="c-tab is-active">
    <div class="c-tab__content">
    <div class="row" id="mapviewer">
        <div class="col-xs-4 nopadding" style="" id="d_d2">
            <div class="dd21 viewer1" id="test111">
                <img class="map" src="images/d/dd2.png" >
                <img class="map" src="images/hover1/mockuptopage_01.png" >
                <img class="map" src="images/hover2/mockuptopage_01.png" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 nopadding" style="" id="n_d2">
            <div class= "nd21 viewer2" id="test222">
                <img class="map" src="images/n/dd2.png" >
                <img class="map" src="images/hover2/mockuptopage_03.png" >
                <img class="map" src="images/hover3/mockuptopage_01.png" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 nopadding" style="" id="s_d2">
            <div class="sd21 viewer3" id="test333">
                <img class="map" src="images/s/dd2.png">
                <img class="map" src="images/hover2/mockuptopage_03.png">
                <img class="map" src="images/hover3/mockuptopage_01.png" >
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#test111').on('mouseover', function() {
    (document).getElementById("test222 img:nth-child(2)").style.display = "inline-block";
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    (document).getElementById("test222:nth-child(2)").style.display = "none";
})
```

Comment: `(document).getElementById("test222 img:nth-child(2)")` is not a valid selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the jQuery selectors, [:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) Selector

```
$('#test111').on('mouseover', function() {
    $("#test222 img:nth-child(2)").css('display', "inline-block");
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $("#test222 img:nth-child(2)").css('display', "none");
})
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically, I used a completely wrong selector. Was there any way to achieve the same result using (document).getElementById() or was it a lost cause from the start?

Comment: @Satpal At SO editing others answers is [encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), especially in cases of little typos like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#test111').on('mouseover', function() {
    $("#test222 img:nth-child(2)").css('display', "inline-block");
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $("#test222 img:nth-child(2)").css('display', "none");
})
```

or without jquery:

```
 $('#test111').on('mouseover', function(){
document.querySelector("#test222 img:nth-child(2)").style.display = "inline-block";
}).on('mouseout', function(){
document.querySelector("#test222 img:nth-child(2)").style.display = "none";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test111').on('mouseover', function() {
     $("#test222")[1].css('display', "inline-block");
}).on('mouseout', function() {
     $("#test222")[1].css('display', "none");
})
```

This should work